# How does Angular handle XSS or CSRF?

Tags: angular, typescript, xss, csrf

How does Angular (2) handle XSS and CSRF. Does it even handle these attacks? 
If so, what do I have to do to use this protection? If not, do I have to handle all these attacks in my server, or somehow with TypeScript in the frontend?

I have read that you have to use "`withCredentials: true`", but I'm not quite sure where to put this code or if it is even that, what I'm looking for.

In the https://angular.io/ webpage I didn't find anything about this (or I just missed it).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Angular2** provides built-in, enabled by default*, anti **XSS** and **CSRF/XSRF** protection.

The [DomSanitizationService](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7a524e3debf85f3cb773e7d4a8914d625ddb256e/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts) takes care of removing the dangerous bits in order to prevent an **XSS** attack.

The [CookieXSRFStrategy](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/10475b859d88570b13bc37b2c97d031e57f85b63/modules/%40angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts) class (within the XHRConnection class) takes care of preventing **CSRF/XSRF** attacks.

*Note that the **CSRF/XSRF** protection is enabled by default on the client but only works if the backend sets a cookie named **XSRF-TOKEN** with a random value when the user authenticates. For more information read up about the [Cookie-to-Header Token pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-Header_Token).

UPDATE: Official Angular2 security documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html (Thanks to Martin Probst for the edit suggestion!).

Comment: Worth looking at that security guide as a whole, but also ref https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection specifically (which the security guide links to)

Answer (score 3):

For mentioned server side in Angular, the CSRF you might handle using Express:

```
app.use(express.csrf())
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.session._csrf);
  res.locals.csrftoken = req.session._csrf;
  next();
})
```

Not sure if with the new **HttpClientXsrfModule** it's still required though. It might be enough to add only the following (but need to be confirmed) on the client side in **app.module**:

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
  cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'
})
```

Comment: perfect explanation

Answer (score 0):

Following is brief guide on how **CSRF** is handled in
backend/server-side implementation when using SpringBoot

The token in **CSRF** can be associated either with  HttpSession or in a cookie

To handle as a **cookie**, we may pass

```
.csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
```

To handle as a **HttpSession**, we may pass

```
.csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository())
```

Even we can have a custom csrf token repository by implmenting CsrfTokenRepository
in case we need skip specific url and so on

all above can be used when overriding  **configure** method of **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**