# regarding CSRF token implementation in GuestPayment

Tags: security, angular, token, csrf

Thanks in advance for your answers.
I have a requirement which is developing in AngularJS 2.0. Requirement prospective, a user can pay his pending bills through GuestPayment portal. this GuestPayment portal does not have any login credentials, it needs to works like BillDesk.com. So how should I implement CSRF token to provide security for this GuestPayment portal or any other tokens are possible? Can you please give me your comments on this.

Comment: See my answer on following similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594516/how-does-angular-2-beta-handle-with-xss-or-csrf/37414222#37414222

Answer (score 0):

Generate a cookie with a token on visit. Grab this token with AngularJS and send this token back as custom header to your backend.
There you can check cookie against custom header.

Answer (score 0):

We now have a security guide including documentation on using XSRF/CSRF protection here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html