# Angular 2/Spring Security CSRF implementation problems

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to build an Angular 2 page on top of a Spring Boot API. I have configured CORS (correctly I believe), but I am getting blocked by Spring Security's CSRF protection.

It is my understanding that [Angular 2 handles CSRF automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414222/545127) as of RC2, and I am on RC4. The server is sending an XSRF token in response to a POST from the Client as seen here:

[image]

I assume that Angular 2 is not picking it up? I know that CORS is working because when I put **.ignoringAntMatchers("/urlhere/")** on the end of **.csrf()** to test, the request went through, so CORS is not blocking it. Here is my config method for HttpSecurity:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/signup/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .headers() 
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

}
```

My Login process on client side consists of a method that first sends credentials, then uses a JWT token to retrieve credentials. The two methods are as follows:

```
sendCredentials(model) {
   let tokenUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/user/login';
   let headers1 = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

   return this.http.post(tokenUrl, JSON.stringify(model), {headers: headers1});
}

sendToken(token){
   let userUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/user/users';
   let headers2 = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token});

   return this.http.get(userUrl, {headers:headers2});
}
```

What am I missing to satisfy the requirements for CSRF protection? Is it client side? Or am I needing to add **/login/** to my list of antMatchers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's late but, I ran into same problem and managed to solve it.
Problem in angular http request:

```
return this.http.post(tokenUrl, JSON.stringify(model), {headers: headers1});
```

You need to adjust it to send like that :

```
return this.http.post(tokenUrl, JSON.stringify(model), {headers: headers1, withCredentials: true});
```

You have to add `withCredentials: true` to all your http requests.
Why you need it? Each time you send http request(OPTIONS, POST etc) to Spring(server) it will generate new XSRF-TOKEN and issue it to client, `withCredentials: true` will save this new XSRF-TOKEN in browser and later on used for new http request, so in case one of your http requests doesn't have `withCredentials: true` it will simply ignore new XSRF-TOKEN and use old(expired) XSRF-TOKEN for http request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It adds to the knowledge base, so I marked it as answered.