# JHipster > Access denied when making a post request

Tags: java, jhipster

I'm trying make a POST request, but when I do (by the Postman) I receive this:

```
{
"error": "access_denied",
"error_description": "Invalid CSRF Token &#39;null&#39; was found on the request parameter &#39;_csrf&#39; or header &#39;X-XSRF-TOKEN&#39;."}
```

But if I make a GET request, works.

My architecture is composed by: traefik/consul, gateway, uaa server and other microservices. 
I have already configured postman with Authorization OAuth 2.0.

My request:

```
http://localhost:8088/bbintegration/api/series?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJ3ZWItYXBwIl0sImV4cCI6MTUwODYxNjU0NywiaWF0IjoxNTA4NjE0NzQ3LCJqdGkiOiJhOTM3Y2UwZS05Y2U3LTRiMWEtOTE5YS05MDE4OTk2NjI2ZjciLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJpbnRlcm5hbCJ9.grCp6uJnUQDKIcEjjCWIYT25m0yWpTpdXV5NrXmY6hSP-N0eliXyxxKy0mS_P5XwXfSW--LvPJwFBNVzXaWIChewgS2cjltA-xUF4WQjbwfWreIxE9s19ywaVo9Sf2bbhlU_e7lHelqN8yFjOjR0R4TOU5AvnofEYWZs6y3g8BqwKb1mf1rl2lxRACk3L-mp8TEAAr8YysyVUtK0UngoB4kpJmWpP2i_7xaJI2LnKQ4OSHEvbZJn32Geo4EyLMBlAoBSfRujkK6vR7EadKFh0wqFzCQiJbPp8xhZZ5Ryk5nUu1UKEcNTQ2XzvKAXImIAf4_jITqhX6kVrEI4sdLxGg
```

JSON:

```
{"code": 11, "description": "SELIC"}
```

My cookie:
[Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNpww.png)

Comment: take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/45237003/2065796

Comment: I have already configured XSRF-TOKEN in the cookie: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNpww.png

Comment: Passing in Header does not works too

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the name of the parameter token is "X-XSRF-TOKEN", not "XSRF-TOKEN" as I was passing. Thanks Oleksandr ;D