# Angular 2 - It makes sense to use csrf token in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, csrf

I make this question because in a client server application the server sends the html with different token hidden in form for each request. This token is built on the server by a secret key.

But Angular 2 all forms are already on the client. For a form contain a token that he needs a secret key is in the client, and that to me is already one security breach.

So I ask the question, if it makes sense to use csrf token in Angular 2? If the answer is yes, how could this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Angular 2 (beta) handle with XSS or CSRF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594516/how-does-angular-2-beta-handle-with-xss-or-csrf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular 2 includes a CSRF/XSRF mitigation strategy known as the [double-submit cookie pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie). From the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#http),

> The Angular http client has built-in support for this technique. The default `CookieXSRFStrategy` looks for a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN and sets an HTTP request header named `X-XSRF-TOKEN` with the value of that cookie on every request. The server must set the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie, and validate the response header for each state modifying request.

So, if you are using the `http` service, you don't need to do anything extra on the Angular side to get CSRF protection. The server needs to check that the header and cookie values are identical.

Comment: Hi Nate, I did a login and sent a form in my app and catch the request that was to the server, and both not find anything with the word `csrf` or `XSRF`. So it appeared cookie but is related to PyCharm. If has by default CSRF protection in Angular 2 how do I activate it?

Comment: @rafaelcb21 What is your backend? I'd recommend posting a separate question with the details of your backend server environment and any relevant code.